# errors converting htaccess file to web.config file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web.config-transform

I have a problem to convert my htaccess file to web.config file,
Am using an MVC PHP project, and every thing was great untill hosting my application, the hoster told me that I must use a web.config file and I created one but It's not working,

this is my htaccess file :

`Options -MultiViews RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myProject/public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]`

and I tried this as a web.config :

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/myProject/public/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="myProject/public/index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

and also I tried to change the parameters "myProject/public" in the url .... and it's not working,

Thanx